# Handling a cron job after a post

Tags: php, image, cron

I'm trying to figure out the best way to do this. Right now I'm allowing users to POST a submission which contains mainly text, but it also uses embedly to grab a relevant thumbnail for the submission.

Embedly is slowing down these POSTs significantly, so I was thinking of just essentially putting a default thumbnail (like reddit does), and then later one run a cron job of a script that goes through all fields which have default thumbnails, and running embedly then to update the thumbnails so the user doesn't have to wait for all the image processing to take place.

Is this the best way to do this? Or are there other ways that I'm overlooking...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the URL's to a database (queue) and have a cron job run a file which fetches the next URL in queue and generate thumbnail from that.

If you see your queue start growing you need to run the cron job more often.

Comment: Nice. When would you suggest that I run the cron job? Every couple of hours?

Comment: Every 5 min would be ok, because the script will not take up any resources, it will only query the database and grab the thumbnail if there is something there. If not just exit quietly and wait 5 min. :)